# How to configure basepath in flask restful api application?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I want to set a basepath for my flask application. I have mentioned one example below.

```
basepath = 'http://localhost:3000/api'
```

i have two api call one is `GET` and other one is `POST` .

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(CreateUser, "/v1/user/create/")
api.add_resource(CreateUser, "/v1/user/details")

class CreateUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
       # Code for creating a user
    def get(self):
       # Code for get the details of user.
```

So here, if i want to create the user then my url will be `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/create/`
so same for `GET` also . So how do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your Api with the path prefix:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, "/api")

...
```

You can't change the host and port this way, you'll have to run flask with parameters:

```
flask run --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3000
```

Or you could do

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, "/api")


...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="3000")
```

Please keep in mind this is not intended for production environments, only for local testing. Please see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/deploy/ for using in a production environment.

If you want to get those values from `basepath`, one option would be `purl`:

```
url = purl.URL('http://localhost:3000/api')
url.host()  # --> "localhost"
url.port()  # --> 3000
url.path()  # --> "/api"
```

Comment: Thanks Petre, Its working . You dont want me to keep 'api = Api(app, "/api")' this on production ?

Comment: No problem @VivekKumar, glad it's working ;-). I meant the part where you start with `flask run` or via code like `app.run(...)`. I'll add a link to the docs about deploying to production.

Comment: Hey @petre , i got other way to handle this let me know which is best . We can configure in application config file something like app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT]='/api' .

Comment: I don't think I can answer that, you'd have to decide depending on your needs. If you'd like the root path to be configurable, go with config (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/).  You can then use flask's configuration mechanisms as you see fit, including creating a configuration file. If it's not going to change, it's probably the same.